# Как правильно выразиться? «Интересующих писать в Директ» или «интересующихся писать в Директ»?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как будет правильно выразиться?

Answer (score 1):

Смотря что вы хотите сказать. Первый вариант выглядит как просторечная форма пожелания "***записать*** в (некий) *Директ тех, кто интересует записывающего*". Второй вариант больше похож на совет "*всем, кому интересно, **писать** письма* в этот самый *Директ*". Неясности (как и впечатление проявленной невежливости) возникают из-за отсутствия глагола-сказуемого перед инфинитивом (*просим, следует, рекомендуем* это делать и т. п.), который обозначал бы совет, требование или рекомендацию. От этого глагола зависит и падеж:

интересующ**им**ся советуем писать туда-то

интересующ**их**ся просим писать туда-то

Стоит подумать и об обращении со словом "Директ". По всей видимости, это лингвистическое изобретение "Яндекса", заменившего кириллицей фрагмент сетевого адреса страницы и увлечённо пишущего инструкции по обращению с тем, что он называет этим словом. Для случайного поста в форуме (для посвящёных) оно может подойти, для формального обращения к аудитории - нет, за неимением в языке такого слова. Как минимум, перед ним требуется *видовое* наименование (сервис "Директ", страница "Директ" и т. п.).

Answer (score 0):

Оба хуже. Фразу надо перестраивать в любом случае.

Вариант "интересующих писать" невозможен в принципе. Интересующих может быть "кого", но не "что".

***"Интересующих меня граждан я просил написать мне."*** - здесь грамматика более или менее соблюдена, хотя фраза все равно выглядит какой-то марсианской, неестественной.
А "интересующих писать" - это даже не просторечие (вопреки Alex_ander), это просто бессмыслица. "Писать" не может выступать субъектом действия.

Ну а что касается варианта "интересующихся писать", то  вот он-то как раз выглядит то ли просторечным, то ли наоборот, слишком канцелярским...

С чем я согласен, что в принципе варианты "интересующихся **просим** писать" и "интересующимся **предлагаем** писать" возможны, хотя и не претендуют на высокий стиль. 
При этом первый лучше, поскольку второй допускает двусмысленность ("кому предлагаем" или "кому писать").